# Creating a function. Error: syntax error at or near ";" OR Error: No language specified

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am creating a function in PostgreSQL for the first time and I am having a problem with the syntax or where exactly to put semicolons;

The function looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(name1 TEXT, int1 INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE new_name TEXT;
DECLARE int2 INTEGER;

BEGIN

...
Some SELECT FROM table queries
...

IF int2 < int1 THEN
    new_name := func(new_name, int1);
ELSE IF int2 = int1 THEN
    RETURN new_name;
ELSE
    RETURN name1;
END IF;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I try to submit this I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 24: END;
            ^
```

If I remove the semicolon after END I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 26: $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
         ^
```

And if I remove the semicolon after END and insert one after the $$ I get

```
$$; LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ERROR:  no language specified
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LANGUAGE"
LINE 1: LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        ^
```

Found the problem. Should have been ELSEIF instead of ELSE IF

Comment: You should provide the answer you have found by supplying it as an answer, that way its clear

Comment: It's `ELSIF` not `ELSE IF` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem:

Should have been `ELSEIF` instead of `ELSE IF`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to remove all but the first DECLARE statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(name1 TEXT, int1 INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE
new_name TEXT;
int2 INTEGER;
BEGIN
...
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'd also highly recommend that you prefix your variables and parameters with something lik v_ or p_ so you don't get them mixed up with column names (which is totally possible).

Comment: Thats not it. I think it has something to do with the IF statements. I took them out and it created the function. With the IF statements, however, it does not.